# How can i save the config of my app without using a database??? (using simple textfile)

Tags: android, persistence

i need to save a simple field to configurate my APP, cause this, i wont use a database (it's only a field...), i need to save true or false value for this field on a file, and everytimes a section of my app wanna check if it is true they have to check this textfile, and not to open a connexion to a database

i need to save the config for ever... i mean that when i exit from my app, and for example, i shut down my android device, when i start my device again and start my app, the config have to be saved

is this possible? how can i do it? i can't find any information about that

EDIT: i have problems with the first answer... this code is on my oncreate method:

```
static SharedPreferences settings;
static SharedPreferences.Editor configEditor;
settings = this.getPreferences(MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

    if (settings.getBoolean("showMeCheckBox", true)) 
     showMeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    else 
     showMeCheckBox.setChecked(false);

applyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks
             if (showMeCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                 configEditor.putBoolean("showMeCheckBox", true); 
                } else {
                 configEditor.putBoolean("showMeCheckBox", false);
                }

            }
});
```

ok, but this doesn't works... allways is selected... always true, like the default value... doesn't matter if i checked or unchecked it.... :S

Comment: See for more information about Shared Preferences [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i suggest not to use a textfile but the Preference Editor.

```
static SharedPreferences settings;
static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
settings = this.getPreferences(MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
editor = settings.edit();
//store value
editor.putString("Preference_name_1", "1");
//get value
//eill return "0" if preference not exists, else return stored value
String val = settings.getString("Preference_name_1", "0");
```

Edit: you have to initialize the configEditor and after setting a value, you have to commit

```
editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("name",true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: but i need to save the config for ever... i mean that when i exit from my app, and for example, i shut down my android device, when i start my device again and start my app, the config have to be saved! it seems that with sharedpreferences i can't do that... :/

Comment: SharedPreferences are "forever" saved. There also is a putBoolean() method available.

Comment: No, its stored until cleanboot. The SharedPreferenceEditor is designed exactly for Problems like yours

Comment: what you mean with cleanboot?

Comment: this method doesn't works for me, i dont understand why, i am adding some more code on first post, please read it

Comment: If you don't need the settings to be immediately written, consider using configEditor.apply(). It is a non blocking method, so faster.