# How to storing data in my own application

Tags: android, storage

I would like to build some simple application - for example Todo list - and I am thinking about the problem and its solving - how can I to store data in my own application on Android platform?

I should to use some text file, xml file or some database? What will be better for beginner on this field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have a VERY hard time getting anywhere with Android if you don't read through their website/dev resources. I would highly recommend visiting their site.

As far as data storage is concerned, that varies based on your need. Explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: It does look like OP hasn't researched much about Android ... @OP: If that's not true, your question should be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use SQLite that comes with Android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, a SQLite database seems most appropriate for this kind of application. There is lots of support for using the SQLite database in conjuction with ListViews (which I imagine you'd want to use in your to-do list app).

In case you haven't already checked it out, see the page on the developer site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 2):

Theres a few ways you can store data. I've created a few applications thats store data using [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

They're quite handy for storing strings, ints, bool values etc. However if you have a large scaled application, that requires better database management, I would look into [sqlLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).

Android has supported classes and functions to help access/store the information.

Theres a good tutorial on the android site called notepad that takes you through how to use sqlite.

That should get you started :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Thread [klick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213960/how-can-i-save-the-config-of-my-app-without-using-a-database-using-simple-tex/4213996#4213996)

Edit: its cool for less data, if you want to store and browse lots of data, you should use as SQLite Database

Answer (score 1):

Using a file, database or xml based depends entirely on what kind of application you are building. For eg: If you parse an XML feed and store the results back in an XML file - it totally defeats the storage purpose!

Databases are used to store structured and related content like - news feed results, email client data, etc.

Files are more used for storing raw / binary content like storing images, attachments, etc.

BTW, if you are a beginner - you should try all of them! :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Accept the answer that worked for you best. This helps better organize the forum and also is useful to others who come here looking for answers.